# YOLO v2 bad accuracy in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently using a custom version of YOLO v2 from pjreddie.com written with Tensorflow and Keras. I've successfully got the model to start and finish training over 100 epochs with 10000 training images and 2400 testing images which I randomly generated along with the associated JSON files all on some Titan X gpus with CUDA. I only wish to detect two classes. However, after leaving the training going, the loss function decreases but the test accuracy hovers at below 3%. All the images appear to be getting converted to black and white. The model seems to perform reasonably on one of the classes when using the training data, so the model appears overfitted. What can I do to my code to get the model to become accurate?

Comment: Okay, so it turned out that YOLOv2 was performing very well on unseen data except that the unseen data has to be the same size of images as the ones it's trained on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out that YOLOv2 was performing very well on unseen data except that the unseen data has to be the same size of images as the ones it's trained on. Don't feed Yolo with 800x800 images if it's been trained on 400x400and 300x400 images. Also the Keras accuracy measure is meaningless for detection. It might say 2% accuracy and actually be detecting all objects. Passing unseen data of the same size solved the problem.